# 0 Search Results in facebook stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, facebook

I am not able to search for any question or even a keyword @ facebook.stackoverflow.com

For anything I search for, its giving : **Your search returned no matches.**

Is site under maintenance?

Comment: Facebook Stack Overflow is just a subsite of Stack Overflow itself, so I doubt it's under maintenance. [facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=timeline](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=timeline) gives 0 results, while [stackoverflow.com/search?q=\[facebook\]+timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[facebook]+timeline) gives 1,333.

Comment: Perhaps this has been fixed- facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=timeline gives 1845 results now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apologies, this was an oversight in some search code.  As stated in comments above facebook.so is a subsite (it doesn't have it's own database)...nor does it have its own search index.  It works off the parent index via a filter at index time, but wasn't correctly pointing to that index.

This has been corrected and a build just pushed out.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the fix.